# How do I select only the filtered rows in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a grid (made with jqGrid 4.15.2). The code looks like the one below:

```
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;

$(function () {
    "use strict";

    var $grid = $("#list"),
        maximizeGrid = function () {
            var newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
            $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
        };

    // Resize grid if window is being resized
    $(window).on("resize", maximizeGrid);

    $grid.jqGrid({
        colNames: ["", "Form #", "Form", "Plan", "Class", "Drug"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "act", template: "actions"},
            {
                name: "FormId",
                align: 'center',
                fixed: true,
                frozen: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 100,
                editable: "hidden"
            },
            {name: "FormName", search: true, stype: "text"},
            {name: "PlanName", search: true, stype: "text"},
            {
                name: "DrugGroupName",
                edittype: "select",
                editable: true,
                search: true,
                editoptions: {
                    dataUrl: "/ajax/drug_groups/get_all",
                    buildSelect: function (data) {
                        var select = "<select>", i;
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            select += "<option value='" + String(data[i].Id) + "'>" + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(data[i].DrugGroupName) + "</option>"
                        }

                        return select + "</select>";
                    },
                    selectFilled: function (options) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(options.elem).select2({
                                width: "100%"
                            });
                        }, 0);
                    }
                },
                stype: "select", searchoptions: {
                    sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                    generateValue: true,
                    noFilterText: "Any",
                    selectFilled: function (options) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(options.elem).select2({
                                width: "100%"
                            });
                        }, 0);
                    }
                }
            },
            {name: "DrugName", search: true, stype: "text"}
        ],
        cmTemplate: {
            width: 300,
            autoResizable: true
        },
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rowNum: 25,
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        autoResizing: {
            compact: true,
            resetWidthOrg: true
        },
        rowList: [25, 50, 100, "10000:All"],
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortable: true,
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        cloneToTop: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiPageSelection: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "Id",
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        prmNames: {id: "Id"},
        jsonReader: {id: "Id"},
        url: '/ajax/plans_to_forms/get_all',
        datatype: "json",
        editurl: '/ajax/plans_to_forms/update',
        formDeleting: {
            url: '/ajax/plans_to_forms/delete/',
            delicon: [true, "left", "fa-scissors"],
            cancelicon: [true, "left", "fa-times"],
            width: 320,
            caption: 'Delete Plan to Form Link',
            msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this link?',
            beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                var rowids = $form.find("#DelData>td").data("rowids");

                $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").position({
                    of: window,
                    my: "center center",
                    at: "center center"
                });

                if (rowids.length > 1) {
                    $form.find("td.delmsg").html('Are you sure you want to delete all the selected form links?');
                }
            },
            afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
                if (response.responseText === "true") {
                    toastr["success"]("The link was deleted successfully.", "Information");
                } else {
                    toastr["error"]("Something went wrong, the link could not be deleted.", "Error");
                }
            }
        },
        ajaxSelectOptions: {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        navOptions: {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            search: false
        },
        inlineEditing: {
            keys: true,
            focusField: "DrugGroupName",
            serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
                var changedData = {}, prop, p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                    idname = p.keyName || p.prmNames.id,
                    oldValue, cm;

                for (prop in postData) {
                    oldValue = p.savedRow[0][prop];
                    if (p.iColByName[prop] != null) {
                        cm = p.colModel[p.iColByName[prop]];
                    }

                    if (postData.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (postData[prop] !== oldValue || prop === idname)) {
                        changedData[prop] = postData[prop];
                    }
                }

                return changedData;
            },
            aftersavefunc: function () {
                toastr["success"]("The record was updated successfully.", "Information");
            },
            errorfunc: function () {
                toastr["error"]("Something went wrong, the record could not be updated.", "Error");
            }
        },
        onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
            var $self = $(this),
                $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
                p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                savedRow = p.savedRow;

            if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
                $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
            }

            if ($td.length > 0 && $td[0].cellIndex !== p.iColByName.act) {
                // don't start editing mode on click on "act" column
                $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
            }
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");

            if (p.datatype === "json") {
                // recreate the toolbar because we use generateValue: true option in the toolbar
                $self.jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar").jqGrid("filterToolbar");
            }
        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid').jqGrid("filterToolbar").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');

    // fill top toolbar
    $('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).append($("<div><label for=\"globalSearchText\">Global search in grid for:&nbsp;</label><input id=\"globalSearchText\" type=\"text\"></input>&nbsp;<button id=\"globalSearch\" type=\"button\">Search</button></div>"));

    $("#globalSearchText").keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        if (key === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) { // 13
            $("#globalSearch").click();
        }
    });

    $("#globalSearch").button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-search"},
        text: false
    }).click(function () {
        var postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
            colModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            rules = [],
            searchText = $("#globalSearchText").val(),
            l = colModel.length,
            i,
            cm;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            cm = colModel[i];
            if (cm.search !== false && (cm.stype === undefined || cm.stype === "text")) {
                rules.push({
                    field: cm.name,
                    op: "cn",
                    data: searchText
                });
            }
        }
        postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "OR",
            rules: rules
        });
        $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {search: true});
        $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1, current: true}]);

        return false;
    });
});
```

When I filter something and then want to mark the filtered results for delete all of them for some reason everything gets selected even those that hasn't been filtered which is sending all the IDs to the backend and therefore I am loosing everything when deleting based on the ID.

Maybe it's an stupid option or something else but I can't find what is wrong. [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/9JKzYY4L5UA) I have made showing up the issue. [Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/Lofcv9vm/) for play with where you can see the issue happening

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Filter the column `Filename` by `test`
- Using the first checkbox mark all of them
- Without un-mark anything, remove the filter
- Result: everything has been selected and therefore will be posted

Any ideas? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem, which you describe, very interesting and thus I changed the default behavior of "Select All" button (checkbox) to select only currently filtered data (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/6ac1b3d6878e4da98fb97b3d30c2470c026fd67d)). The new option `selectAllMode` with the value `"all"` allows to have the old behavior.

Your demo uses the latest free jqGrid directly from GitHub and thus it should work already like you want.

Comment: I need to make a hotfix for this, do you have a minimized version of this commit already?

Comment: @ReynierPM: I build src/min/map on every change of some part of source code. You can load min file from [here](https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js) or download all files from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/archive/master.zip).